# Running powershell script within python script, how to make python print the powershell output while it is running

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, powershell, stdout

I am writing a python script which checks various conditions and runs a powershell script accordingly to help me automate migration from windows XP to windows 7. The powershell script gives its own output giving the user updates as to what is happening. I would like to take the output of the powershell script and print it as output of the python script. I have looked around at some questions which seem to want to do the same thing but they don't seem to be working for me. Initially I tried using

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["C:\Users\gu2124\Desktop\helloworld.ps1"])
```

As was suggested here [Run PowerShell function from Python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14508809/run-powershell-function-from-python-script) but I found out that this waits for the program to execute first and does not give output so I found out I need to use `subprocess.Popen()` as was suggusted here [Use Popen to execute a Powershell script in Python, how can I get the Powershell script's output and update it to web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4668610/use-popen-to-execute-a-powershell-script-in-python-how-can-i-get-the-powershell) so I tried this

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["C:\Users\gu2124\Desktop\helloworld.ps1"], stdout=sys.stdout)
```

and I get this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gu2124\Desktop\pstest.py", line 5, in <module>
    subprocess.Popen(["C:\Users\gu2124\Desktop\helloworld.py1"], stdout=sys.stdout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 701, in __init__
    errread, errwrite), to_close = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 848, in _get_handles
    c2pwrite = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(stdout.fileno())
  File "<string>", line 523, in __getattr__
  File "C:\Program Files\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\netref.py", line 150, in __getattr__
    return syncreq(self, consts.HANDLE_GETATTR, name)
  File "C:\Program Files\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\netref.py", line 71, in syncreq
    return conn.sync_request(handler, oid, *args)
  File "C:\Program Files\PyScripter\Lib\rpyc.zip\rpyc\core\protocol.py", line 434, in sync_request
    raise obj

AttributeError: DebugOutput instance has no attribute 'fileno'
```

I'm not completely sure what this means but from what I think I understand after reading this [AttributeError: StringIO instance has no attribute 'fileno'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903501/attributeerror-stringio-instance-has-no-attribute-fileno) is that it is because I am messing with the stdout incorrectly. I looked a around more and I found this [Why won't my python subprocess code work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16544362/why-wont-my-python-subprocess-code-work) where the answers said to use `stdout=subprocess.PIPE` so I tried this

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["C:\Users\gu2124\Desktop\helloworld.ps1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

which also does not give me output
Finally I saw this http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/os/subprocess-for-system-administrators and changed my code to this

```
import subprocess
p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell","C:\Users\gu2124\Desktop\helloworld.ps1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
print p.communicate
```

I thought that it may because I am initially trying to run a powershell script from the command line so I have to open powershell first. When I type these commands directly into the command line it works the way it should but when I run it through the python script it gives this

```
<bound method Popen.communicate of <subprocess.Popen object at 0x00000000026E4A90>>
```

which is an improvement I guess but not the "Hello world" I was expecting. 
I have no idea what I should try to do next to get this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Also if the powershell script I am using is needed here it is

```
$strString = "Hello World"
write-host $strString

function ftest{
$test = "Test"
write-host $test
}
```

EDIT: I tried upgrading to python 3.3 like was suggested in the first answer but I still can't get it to work. I used the command `p = subprocess.Popen(['powershell.exe', "C:\\Users\\gu2124\\Desktop\\helloworld.ps1"], stdout=sys.stdout)` and am sure the file is there but am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#3>", line 1, in <module>
    p = subprocess.Popen(['powershell.exe', "C:\\Users\\gu2124\\Desktop\\helloworld.ps1"], stdout=sys.stdout)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 701, in __init__
    errread, errwrite), to_close = self._get_handles(stdin, stdout, stderr)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\subprocess.py", line 848, in _get_handles
    c2pwrite = msvcrt.get_osfhandle(stdout.fileno())
UnsupportedOperation: fileno
```

Comment: When you write `print p.communicate`, you are printing out the method object, not printing out the results of the method that was run. You'd need to change it to `print p.communciate()` to get the results you want.

Comment: You also don't import the sys module, which makes calling sys.stdout fail. The UnsupportedOperation means your operating system does not support fileno(). If you look here: http://forums.devshed.com/python-programming-11/python27-pyserial-windows-broken-select-fileno-827240.html, it refers to a document that mentions fileno() is unix only. If `subprocess.Popen()` isn't working for you, you may try `os.system()`, though it is deprecated.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

1. Make sure you can run powershell scripts (it is disabled by default). Likely you have already done this. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176949.aspx

   ```
   Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
   ```
2. Run this python script on your powershell script `helloworld.py`:

   ```
   # -*- coding: iso-8859-1 -*-
   import subprocess, sys

   p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", 
                 "C:\\Users\\USER\\Desktop\\helloworld.ps1"], 
                 stdout=sys.stdout)
   p.communicate()
   ```

This code is based on python3.4 (or any 3.x series interpreter), though it should work on python2.x series as well.

```
C:\Users\MacEwin\Desktop>python helloworld.py
Hello World
```

Comment: The tricky part here, that is not at all obvious to non PS and Py experts, is that if you have many powershell command-line arguments (or very long/complex one-liners), you **have** to invoke the shell with an array, where each item is a separate argument. Otherwise you risk wasting hours trying to debug why the output is not what you expect.

Answer (score 7):

In addition to the previous answers, I have some suggestions which makes your code more portable.

Instead of setting `ExecutionPolicy` globally to `RemoteSigned` (which imposes some security issues) you can use this to set it only for the PowerShell instance created by your Python script:

```
import subprocess, sys    
p = subprocess.Popen('powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -file "hello world.ps1"', stdout=sys.stdout)
p.communicate()
```

Note the quotes which allows your PowerShell-script's path/filename to contain spaces.

Furthermore, as shown in the above example, you can use a relative path to call your PowerShell script. The path is relative to your Python workspace directory.

Comment: Using relative path does not work if you run python with admin

Comment: I actually think it does also work when Python is ran using admin privileges. You only have to make sure your Python instance uses the proper workspace directory.

Answer (score 6):

I don't have Python 2.7 installed, but in Python 3.3 calling `Popen` with `stdout` set to `sys.stdout` worked just fine. Not before I had escaped the backslashes in the path, though.

```
>>> import subprocess
>>> import sys
>>> p = subprocess.Popen(['powershell.exe', 'C:\\Temp\\test.ps1'], stdout=sys.stdout)
>>> Hello World
_
```

Comment: I tried changing my code like you suggested and upgrading to python 3.3 but it still doesn't work...I edited the question to reflect my new output and code

Answer (score 2):

This is how I get the output from Popen

```
p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell","C:\Users\gu2124\Desktop\helloworld.ps1"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
p_out, p_err = p.communicate()

print(p_out)
```

From the docs on Popen.communicate(). The function returns a tuple (stdout_data, stderr_data).