# How to convert Powershell function to work within Python script?

Tags: python-2.7, powershell

I have a function in Powershell which given a path to a folder, returns a computed hash. I need it to work within a Python script. My question is: how can I convert it to work within Python? Thanks.

```
function Get-FolderHash ($folder) {
 dir $folder -Recurse | ?{!$_.psiscontainer} | %{[Byte[]]$contents += [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($_.fullname)}
 $hasher = [System.Security.Cryptography.SHA1]::Create()
 $a = [string]::Join("",$($hasher.ComputeHash($contents) | %{"{0:x2}" -f $_}))
 Write-Host $a
}
Get-FolderHash "PATH_TO_FOLDER"
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple option can let Python execute Powershell and capture the std_out:

> import subprocess, sys
>
> p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", 
>                "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\helloworld.ps1"], 
>                stdout=sys.stdout)
>
> p.communicate()

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944895/running-powershell-script-within-python-script-how-to-make-python-print-the-pow)

***But*** perhaps you can also try to take out Powershell and let Python handle everything

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'd rather have the powershell code within the script to  avoid file dependencies. I must use Powershell because I actually want to perform this command on a remote system, which I cannot do with Python.

Comment: Depending on what remote means in that context you could also just setup a file share on the remote side and use that ... clunky but works in various circumstances.