# found error while trying to run print('hello world') by a python script that executes the code within powershell

Tags: python, powershell

I am currently trying to run a simple hello world program in powershell using this code :

```
import subprocess
import sys

p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe",
                 'C:/users/m.m/Desktop/hello.ps1'],
                 stdout = sys.stdout)
p.communicate()
```

what i'm trying to do is this; i have saved the "**hello.ps1**" python program  with powershell extension containing `print("hello, world!")` in desktop and **I want to create a program that reads the file within my python files , opens them and runs those scripts in powershell after invoking python by `python` command**.

I have already tried the code above as suggested in here ==> [Running powershell script within python script, how to make python print the powershell output while it is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944895/running-powershell-script-within-python-script-how-to-make-python-print-the-pow), but it gives me security error.

This is the error that i get when run the code above:

```
C:/users/m.m/Desktop/hello.ps1 : File C:\users\m.m\Desktop\hello.ps1 cannot 
be loaded because running scripts is 
disabled on this system. For more information, see about_Execution_Policies 
at 
https:/go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=135170.
At line:1 char:1
+ C:/users/m.m/Desktop/hello.ps1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : SecurityError: (:) [], PSSecurityException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnauthorizedAccess
```

The main goal is this:using python to write scripts for powershell.

Comment: Seems like a permission error, try running the python script as administrator.

Comment: You've shown us `C:\users\m.m\Desktop\hello.ps1` is being targetted, however, you've not shown us the code being ran on this, could you add this to your question.

Comment: Dear @Matthew, it's just a simple `print('hello world')`

Comment: That would be the Python Syntax, PowerShell it would be `write-host "hello, world!"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting that error likely for two reasons, the first is because you're not running PowerShell as an administrator, you should save your script and reload ISE as an administrator.

Secondly, you must set run the following:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

or

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy unrestricted
```

Run this before you run your script.

Additional information on `Set-ExecutionPolicy` can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.security/set-executionpolicy?view=powershell-6)

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you can run powershell scripts (it is disabled by default).
Run this as an *Administrator* into your PowerShell window

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

because the error that you're getting is

> cannot  be loaded because running scripts is  disabled on this system.

Comment: how to mention the code you wrote above in my code ?

Comment: you don't mention that in your code, you just copy this & paste it in your powershell window(which is running as administrator) & then execute your script

Comment: aha!.., got it.