# How to Run a Specific Powershell Command Within Python with a Defined Variable and Print Output?

Tags: python, string, powershell, subprocess, getcwd

I am trying to run a specific command from Python to Powershell:

The command works as expected in Powershell. The command in Powershell is as following:

```
 gpt .\Method\gpt_scripts\s1_cal_deb.xml -t .\deburst\S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20180909T003147_20180909T003214_023614_0292B2_753E_Cal_deb_script.dim .\images\S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20180909T003147_20180909T003214_023614_0292B2_753E.zip
```

Powershell Output:

[image]

```
os.getcwd()

'C:\\Users\\Ishack\\Documents\\Neta-Analytics\\Harvest Dates\\S1_SLC_Processing'
```

The  current directory is the same as in PowerShell

I tried something like this:

```
import subprocess


process = 'gpt .\Method\gpt_scripts\s1_cal_deb.xml -t .\deburst\S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20180909T003147_20180909T003214_023614_0292B2_753E_Cal_deb_script.dim .\images\S1A_IW_SLC__1SDV_20180909T003147_20180909T003214_023614_0292B2_753E.zip'

process = subprocess.Popen(['powershell.exe', '-NoProfile', '-Command', '"&{' + process + '}"'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)


process
```

Output:

```
<subprocess.Popen at 0x186bb202388>
```

But when I press enter I get no response, I would like Python to print out the output just like in Powershell.  I researched other similar questions but still no solution to the problem.

Thanks,

Ishack

Comment: This might help. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944895/running-powershell-script-within-python-script-how-to-make-python-print-the-pow

Comment: Hi Sharmag, I tried but it denies the operation.

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
os.system("powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .\SamplePowershell.ps1")
```

SamplePowershell.ps1

```
Write-Host "Hello world"
hostname
```

This worked for me. Commands in file *SamplePowershell.ps1*.

and if you want to use *subprocess*

```
import subprocess
k=subprocess.Popen('powershell.exe hostname', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE);
print(k.communicate())
```