# Is there a way I can remove all Windows's restore points with Python?

Tags: python

Every time when I'm uninstalling a software (Revo Uninstaller Pro), a new Windows restore point is created, and I want to create a simple script that I will put on my Desktop, that every time I click on it, my Windows's restore points will be deleted, But I don't want to fully disable it because this is important.

I have asked Google, but I didn't find anything about it with Python.

Is there a way I can delete all Windows's restore points ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this directly with python. You need to run a power shell script that does this and invoke it from python.

Microsoft already wrote the power shell script for you: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Script-to-delete-System-4960775a

How to invoke a power shell script from python  [Running powershell script within python script, how to make python print the powershell output while it is running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944895/running-powershell-script-within-python-script-how-to-make-python-print-the-pow)

Comment: I can't do it with the `ctypes` module in Python ?