# Executing PowerShell lines in python

Tags: python, windows, powershell, arduino

I am working on a camera setup which could track a face when rotating camera on some servo motors. The way I want to do it (the way it's possible for me to do it) is like this: I use python openCV to get a face position and generate a vector which tells how much to turn to what direction so that the camera would look straight in a face. That vector is then sent to Arduino Uno where the input vector is decoded into a servo motor movement using Arduino IDE. The problem is sending vectors calculated in python script to Arduino. I used PowerShell commands to send said vectors to **COM10** via Windows terminal:

```
$port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM10, 9600, None, 8, one
$port.open()
$port.Writeline(vector)
$port.close()
```

When I use python os or subprocess commands like this:

```
os.system("powershell $port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM10, 9600, None, 8, one")
os.system("powershell $port.open()")
```

Or

```
subprocess.run(["powershell", "-Command", "$port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM10, 9600, None, 8, one"])
subprocess.run(["powershell", "-Command", "$port.open()"])
```

The first line works well, however the **port** variable I assume is not saved and I get a following error on the second line:

```
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At line:1 char:1
+ $port.open()
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

In the whole python script I only need one line to be executed repeatedly, because I get a live feed of a video from camera:

```
$port.Writeline(vector)
```

The other lines are used only when the script starts and stops running.

I tried many other things, like writing these 4 lines in PowerShell script and the executing it, but I can't even get that script to run on my terminal, etc.
Will this kind of approach even work and I could fix it or should I just straight up give up with it an use something else?
If it is possible then what could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your issue here is that you are running the commands as **subprocess**. Once you run the first command `os.system("powershell $port= new-Object System.IO.Ports.SerialPort COM10, 9600, None, 8, one")` you have define the `$port` variable in a new process, and then that process exits and no longer exists.

When you run `os.system("powershell $port.open()")` you are creating a new process which has no knowledge that a `$port` variable has ever existed.

You will want to look at storing that script in its entirety in a separate file and run the whole script at once. This will also make that script easier for you to edit and debug later if you have any issues.

See [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21944895/running-powershell-script-within-python-script-how-to-make-python-print-the-pow) for help with running the script.