# How to check if a python script has been copied/accessed on windows

Tags: python

I was wondering if there is a python module that essentially allows for checking whether your python script has been accessed/copied (and which user has done it) from a shared resource. More of a curiosity as most google searches have shown results relating to 'checking if a file copy is complete' and not necessarily 'if a file has been accessed/copied' and by who
Thank you!

Comment: A file access / modification is handled by OS, not a python module. There could be some way in the respective OS to see that access log (eg. Audit logs in Windows Server).

Answer (score 0):

As @Kris told System log files controlled by OS...There is an way you can get this...Simply follow steps..

```
1)Create a PowerShell script that will access system log files..Follow below link.
```

Link: [Powershell script refrence](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-eventlog?view=powershell-5.1#:%7E:text=The%20Get%2DEventLog%20cmdlet%20gets,values%20to%20search%20for%20events.)

Next

```
run that powershell script using python
```

Link: [Running powershell script within python script, how to make python print the powershell output while it is running](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21944895/15358800)